# MySQL 8 week report

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make an 8 week sales report, but I read that I must not use the week('date') = # to avoid performance issues. My plan was to get the MAX for week value and then substract from 1 to 7 to show the sum of 8 weeks for a

`select sum(tot) 
from venta 
where week('date') = MAX(week( (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(fec, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')) , 0)) -7`

Any ideas how can I do this? This is my table structure and 1 row if needed.

```
id  int(255)    NO  PRI     auto_increment
can int(11) NO          
tot double  NO          
fec varchar(30) NO          
hor varchar(20) NO          
cod_f   varchar(10) YES MUL     
per_f   varchar(30) YES MUL     
tdt varchar(15) NO          
des double  YES             
cdv varchar(15) NO          
cliente varchar(100)    YES         
fdc varchar(30) YES         
local   varchar(25) NO          

id  can tot fec         hor             cod_f    per_f tdt  des              cdv    cliente fdc         local   
1   1   179 10/08/2014  11:10:35 a.m.   1158        D   0   CAMBIO DE PILA  1492    YESENIA 10/08/2014  KCRIS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(tot) 
from venta 
where yearweek(date) between yearweek(curdate() - interval 7 week) 
                         and yearweek(curdate())
```